# Обнуление элементов матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, vector

нужно обнулить элементы выше главной и выше побочной диагонали,написал такой код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n/ 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1 + i; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Почему-то элементы,которые лежат непосредственно на диагоналях,не обнуляет.

Comment: Ну а разве у вас `j` может принимать, например, то же значение, что и `i` - чтобы обнулять главную диагональ? Ну что стоит аккуратно нарисовать матрицу и посмотреть, чему должны быть равны `i` и `j`?...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n+1)/2; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < n - i; ++j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]